# How can Nautilus autodiscover a NAS?

Tags: nautilus, mount, nas

I have two machines: a 12.10 which autodiscovers my NAS fine and a 13.04 which does not autodiscover the NAS in Nautilus. The latter does not display the drive in Nautilus.

I did install samba on the 13.04, I think a while ago, but I cannot remember what I did. Before I connected to the drive using afp, now I notice the 12.10 uses smb.

How can I make my 13.04 autodiscover the NAS and how should I configure it?

Comment: Would a simple bookmark in nautilus do it? I know that's not the answer for the question you are looking for, but its convenient ;)

Comment: That would be nice *if* Nautilus could actually find the NAS.

Comment: It's actually the other way around: Nas discovered Nautilus by Bob James, and its has been one of [Nas' favorite albums](https://www.complex.com/music/2012/05/nas-25-favorite-albums/bob-james-one) ever since!